# How do I best reference a generator function in the parent class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class hierarchy and in the parent class, I have a generator function which I sometimes need to use as is.  In the derived class, I have a preferred generator.  If I use  `super()` to assign the parent generator function to a variable (that is, a pointer to function), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 22, in <module>
    for i in baz.generator():
  File "foo.py", line 11, in generator
    for i in self.f():
AttributeError: 'bar' object has no attribute 'f'
```

The following code works, but it uses the parent class name (`foo`) directly.  My question relates to the method `bar.generator`:  Is there a reasonable way of writing this to avoid directly referencing classes `bar` and `foo`?  The other two generators should not be touched.

```
class foo(object):    # base
    def generator(self):
        for i in range(10):
            yield i

class bar(foo):       # derived
    def generator(self, override=True):
        f = bar.generator2 if override else foo.generator
        for i in f(self):
            yield i

    def generator2(self):
        for i in range(10):
            yield 2*i

baz = bar()
L = []
for i in baz.generator():   # use baz.generator2
    L.append(i)
print(L)
L = []                      # use foo.generator
for i in baz.generator(override=False):
    L.append(i)
print(L)
```

Comment: Where did you try to use `super`? Your code (and traceback) do not show it. Note that Python uses `names`, not `variables`. Thinking like "a variable (that is, a pointer to function)" is fine for other languages - but makes it harder for you to understand what's happening in Python. Inside your methods `self` is the `name` referring to the object (here: "self" is the name of the same thing named by "baz"), whereas 'foo` and `bar` are the names of classes.  You need the methods belonging to the object not classes, so something like `self.generator` and `self.generator2` will be more useful.

Comment: Yeah, while explaining I just want to agree with the above, it is probably best to leave the whole "pointer" terminology behind, while it might be helpful explaining some of the semantics in python to someone coming from a different language, it is probably best to understand python on its own terms, and *python doesn't have pointers*. Functions are first-class objects, exactly the same in that regard to a `list` or an `int`. Assigning a function to a variable is as mundane as assigning an `int` or a `list` to a variable

Comment: @jalanb ```bar.generator``` and ```self.generator``` are not the same.  The former is a the method in the class taking ```self``` as its first argument and the latter is the instance method.  But thinking about your comment helped me figure out what was wrong.  Sorry about the missing details. A few things were lost in editing while trying to get the post to pass.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga point taken.  It's probably obvious that *python* is neither my first nor my primary programming language.

Answer (score 0):

The comments were quite helpful.  The following two line change takes care of the problem:

```
class bar(foo):       # derived
    def generator(self, override=True):
        f = self.generator2 if override else super().generator
        for i in f():
            yield i
```

The changes are `self.generator2` for `bar.generator`, `super()` for `foo` and `f()` for `f(self)` since `f` now refers to the method in the object.